# Colocar iconos sobre un menu con bootstrap4

Tags: html, css, html5, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Tengo un pequeño problema, estoy intentando hacer un footer donde tenga unos iconos arriba y debajo tenga un navbar, algo parecido a esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

E hice un esto :

```
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-12 in-line d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
                    <i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i>
                    <i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center icons">
                            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-sucess my-navbar">
                                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                                </button>
                                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                                 <strong>
                                  <ul class="navbar-nav">
                                    <li class="nav-item active">
                                      <a class="nav-link" href="#"><p>Home</p></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">My gifts</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Register</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login </a>
                                    </li>
                                  </ul>
                                  </strong>
                                </div>
                          </nav>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 ">
                    <p class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

pero el problema es que me esta quedando mucho espacio intermedio entre cada salto de línea? Lo que necesito es que estén mas cerca uno del otro como el ejemplo que di.

Lo intente hacer sin colocarle  y  pero me sale uno al lado del otro .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actualmente son elementos de la barra de navegación que tienen unos padding y márgenes que hacen que haya "mucho" espacio. Si pones en 0 dichas propiedades, tienes un resultado mucho más "ajustado". Ya depende de ti como quieras modificar dichos 0 por otro valor.

```css
.footer .navbar,
.footer .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
}

.footer .nav-link p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-12 in-line d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
                    <i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i>
                    <i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center icons">
                            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-sucess my-navbar">
                                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                                </button>
                                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                                 <strong>
                                  <ul class="navbar-nav">
                                    <li class="nav-item active">
                                      <a class="nav-link" href="#"><p>Home</p></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">My gifts</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Register</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login </a>
                                    </li>
                                  </ul>
                                  </strong>
                                </div>
                          </nav>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 ">
                    <p class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

    </div>
</div>
```